# Parallels Desktop Minimum Hard Disk Space to allocate?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, spaces, parallels-desktop

My current hard disk drive 256GB is already not enough for me. Therefore, I wish to reduce the allocation of my Parallels Desktop.

I did the "Reclaim" to get 11GB back, but PD still occupies 63.6GB. My Windows is just like an "emergency Window environment", which does not necessarily take up so large space. **Can I further reduce the space occupied by PD?**

The reclaim button now is grey and unclickable, indicating that I cannot further claim more space back for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the space each VM actually takes it is dynamic. For example Windows might say 64GB of space remain, but in reality the size of the image it is in is actually a lot smaller. See here:

[image: Windows REAL Size on Disk]

As you can see it only takes up 34GB rather than 64GB. A way to reduce space would be to uninstall applications or features you do not need within windows. I have done this with my Windows 8 VM.

Comment: features you do not need within windows? for example, please?

Comment: Extra programs. If you are virtualizing windows 8 you can uninstall some of the home screen applications for example. You can also disable hibernation within the virtual machine to save some space. See here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/delete-hiberfilsys-by-disabling-windows-hibernate-function/

Comment: You can disable hibernation with Windows 7 to regain a few gigabytes as well.

Comment: May I ask how to disable that? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Go to Start then search for cmd. Right click on cmd.exe and run it as administrator. When the window opens enter "powercfg -h off" without the quotes. This should save you some space.